# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x165d5150'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsarray

Hi I am getting this data form server

```
NSDictionary*feed=[saveDic objectForKey:@"feed"];
NSLog(@"%@",feed); //Outputs: feed = ( { code = yQ7j0t; "user_id" = 889445341091863; } ); }
NSLog(@"%@",[feed valueForKey:@"code"]);
NSString *referralCode = [feed valueForKey:@"code"];
NSLog(@"%@",referralCode);
self.referralCode.text=referralCode;
```

And beacuse of that I am getting below error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: selector sent to instance 0x165d5150'``
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the output for that `NSLog(@"%@",feed);`

Comment: What is the output of those NSLogs ?

Comment: feed =     (
                {
            code = yQ7j0t;
            "user_id" = 889445341091863;
        }
    );
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, your `feed` key holds an array. You are not properly handling that in your code, that is why the crash occurs. When you call `valueForKey:` it retrieves an array of values held by that specific key.

For fixing that you can use:

```
NSArray *feed          = [saveDic objectForKey:@"feed"];
NSArray *referralCodes = [feed valueForKey:@"code"];
NSString *referralCode = referralCodes.count ? referralCodes[0] : @"";
NSLog(@"%@",referralCode);
```

But I personally prefer using `objectForKey:` instead of `valueForKey:`. So you can re-write the code like:

```
NSArray *feed          = [saveDic objectForKey:@"feed"];
NSString *referralCode = feed.count ? [feed[0] objectForKey:@"code"] : @"";
NSLog(@"%@",referralCode);
```

Comment: thank you very much.. may i now diff b/w objectForKey & valueForKey

Comment: :) Happy coding. means

Comment: @SudheerKumar: Code happily (Don't worry, I always say that to SO mates) :)

Answer (score 0):

Some where you use a variable;

```
yourVaribleName.length
```

or

```
[yourVaribleName length]
```

which should be

```
yourVaribleName.count
```

note: the crash says exactly that "**yourVaribleName**" is **NSArray** type where you wants **length** of the **NSArray**. But **NSArray** has not feature "**length**". NSArray has "**Count**"  feature

//try with this code bellow

```
NSArray *referralCode = [feed valueForKey:@"code"];
NSLog(@"%@",referralCode);
self.referralCode.text=[referralCode componentsJoinedByString:@" "];//@"," or @"" what event you need
```

Comment: in which line crash occur

Comment: but i want to add to NSArray to label field

Comment: while add to label field

Comment: self.referralCode.text=referralCode;

Comment: self.referralCode.text = [referralCode componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

Comment: do this if "referralCode" is Array

Comment: then you crash will remove

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92704/discussion-between-jamil65able-and-sudheer-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Your feed data is in array. So you have retrieve code value from array.Hope it will help you.

```
 NSMutableArray*feed=[saveDic objectForKey:@"feed"];
    NSLog(@"%@",feed);
    NSLog(@"%@",[feed valueForKey:@"code"]);
    NSString *referralCode =  [[feed objectAtIndex:indexPath]valueForKey:@"code"];
    NSLog(@"%@",referralCode);
    self.referralCode.text=referralCode;
```